# Repeater template control with custom events

Tags: asp.net, templates, event-handling

I'm writing item template for repeater in separate control, and then I'm using following code:

```
HospitalRepeater.DataSource = LocationsList;
HospitalRepeater.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("~/UserControls/HospitalDetails.ascx");
HospitalRepeater.DataBind();
```

This code worked fine, however now we want to add custom events to HospitalDetails control.

We created following event with custom event args:

```
public class HospitalItemEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Int32 HospitalID { get; set; }

    public HospitalItemEventArgs() { }

    public HospitalItemEventArgs(Int32 hID)
    {
        this.HospitalID = hID;
    }
}


public event EventHandler<HospitalItemEventArgs> HospitalAction;

protected virtual void OnHospitalAction(HospitalItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (HospitalAction!= null)
        this.HospitalAction(this, e);
}
```

Now here is a problem - I can't access this custom event from my code after loading this control as template, because it returns object of System.Web.UI.ITemplate.
I assumed that this is wrapper above my exact control, but this assumtion is wrong.

Cast to my control type fails with following error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'SimpleTemplate' to type 'UserControls.HospitalDetails'.
```

I've tried reverse action - load control using

```
Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/HospitalDetails.ascx");
```

It returns object of correct HospitalDetails type, but It does not implement ITemplate interface.

Whan I tried to do that I've received error message:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.usercontrols_hospitaldetails_ascx' to type 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate'.
```

Can anyone help me to deal with this cast, or find another solution which matches following requrements:

- Repeater should be bound to list of HospitalItems to display details.
- Template for displaying details should hide it's UI interactions and expose few simple events like HospitalAction with hospital ID.
- Separate object must have ability to subscribe to this events.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by having an event on your item template?

Comment: I want to create event that happens on some user interaction, and expose it like 'HospitalAction' with particular ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to create some `<asp:Button />` controls specifying the `CommandName` and `CommandArgument` attributes. You can then handle the bubbled even on the repeater itself, interrogate the arguments for `CommandName` and `CommandArgument`.

I'm not using a separate control as a template but the same thing can be accomplished like this.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="SaveButton"
                    CommandName="Save" 
                    CommandArgument="{insert hospitol ID here}" 
                    Text="Save"
                    runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

    void myRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Save")
        {
            int id = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            //Do some saving
        }
    }
```

**Update**

The purpose for the button's `CommandArgument` and `CommandName` attributes is to allow you to provide the user with individual actions to take on databound ui content. The `CommandArgument` attribute is to allow you a point of entry back into the data to retrieve the relevant information for the event. I have never tried to put multiple values in this attribute, but I do not see a reason why it would not work.

Another option is to create a separate list that contains HospitalID and DoctorID associations, create a unique ID for each association and store that list in a database (if you need to persist it), cache (if used by multiple users), session (if used by multiple pages by same user) or Viewstate (if used by a single page and the list is relatively short).

Comment: Thank you, that will work in my case. However it does not solves common problem. What if I need to pass more than 1 parameter? Should I pass something like "7;35" and remember that 7 is Hospital ID and 35 is Doctor ID. What if event will be result of complex interactions not simple click? Should I create invisible LinkButton with CommandName and trigger it's click to emulate event? I'll appreciate any ideas to make this code better.

Comment: See my updates above. What complex events is the user undergoing? Is this something that can be handled by server side code?